# Why does "Software Updater" prevent resume from suspend?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, update-manager, resume

I think I have found out the cause of this really annoying failure to resume from suspend on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Every time the Asus K52F fails to resume from suspend (no screen activity, no disk activity?? and no CD ROM check), Software Updater pops up after doing the obligatory hard reboot (hold down power button for 5 seconds).

Could this program somehow,prevent the laptop from resuming from suspend?

Comment: Software Updater wouldn't block resume.  Suspend on its own is very finnicky, and can be glitchy on some hardware - this is more likely a problem with Resume on your hardware in general than any specific piece of software preventing resume.  Software Updater is telling you that updates are available, but it's not a system-modal or blocking program that'd block your resume.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why everytime it does fail to resume, Software Updater shows up. Maybe it is just because everytime you reboot Software Updater shows up?

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is when I press a keyboard button, the power light on the upper right part of the laptop goes from blinking to solid white light. So it at least responded to a keypress. But no CD_ROM check and no display backlight. There WAS a time several months ago when resume worked perfectly. But after some fairly recent update, it went back to the occassional faliure to resume. ALso the update messed up my screen brightness again. When I resume, the screenbrightness is super dim so I hafta manually bring the brightness up again with a of Fn-F6 keypresses.